# Client-Server connection with sockets

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I have a program that multiple clients would be able to connect to a server using a socket:

```
private void performConnect()
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (myList.Pending())
        {
            thrd = thrd + 1;
            tcpClient = myList.AcceptTcpClient();

            IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = (IPEndPoint)tcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint;
            string clientIP = ipEndPoint.Address.ToString();
            nStream[thrd] = tcpClient.GetStream();
            currentMsg = "\n New IP client found :" + clientIP;
            recieve[thrd].Start();

            this.Invoke(new rcvData(addNotification));
            try
            {
                addToIPList(clientIP);

            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException exp)
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine(exp.Message);
            }
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }           
    }       
}
```

then the server could send data (chat messages) to a chosen client, using this code.

```
private void sendData(String data)
{
    IPAddress ipep =IPAddress.Parse(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
    Socket server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork , SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    IPEndPoint ipept = new IPEndPoint( ipep, hostPort);
    NetworkStream nStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
    ASCIIEncoding asciidata = new ASCIIEncoding();
    byte[] buffer = asciidata.GetBytes(data);
    if (nStream.CanWrite)
    {
        nStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        nStream.Flush();
    }
}
```

the problem is that whatever IP i choose from the combo box, the message i send would always be directed/sent to the last IP that connected to the server.. Please somebody pinpoint my error! all help would be appreciated.

Comment: Edit your title and make it different from the first line of problem description.

Comment: Well, make it encapsulate the question being asked.

Answer (score 0):

Look at those lines:

```
IPAddress ipep =IPAddress.Parse(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
Socket server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork , SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
IPEndPoint ipept = new IPEndPoint( ipep, hostPort);
NetworkStream nStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
```

You are creating a new socket but you are sending the data to the socket stored in the variable `tcpClient` that is global (since it was not defined in the method), thus totally ignoring the IPEndPoint parsed from the combobox.

You should not create a new socket in order to send data to the clients. Instead, store all clients in a collection and retrieve the appropriate one based on the input of the combobox.